# TinyMCE table not working/loading correctly on material-ui Modal

Tags: reactjs, tinymce, tinymce-plugins

I'm using the currrent last version of TinyMCE, and i'm having a struggle with the table plugin. On my project i import the editor in two instances, one on a separate page dedicated only to the editor, and a second one that is being displayed on a material-ui Modal, to make some minor changes over the document.

What happens is that the table plugin seems not to be loading correctly, since i can add whatever columns and rows i want, but they appeared to be disabled to only add a 1x1 table.
[Table grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiYlH.png)

Also... and this is the one that worries me most. Is that the table properties when i focus the table, are not displaying the actual properties window/popup.

[TableProps on focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2dHO.png)

And if i decided to access those properties by right clicking the table, although the properties windows show up, i cannot change anything there, all properties seems to be disabled.

[Properties disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6C7s.png)

If anyone have solution to fix this issue it would really help a lot!

Thank you by advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Material UI by default blocks the focus from leaving the modal dialog as noted here: https://mui.com/components/modal/#focus-trap. This then prevents you from interacting with any popups TinyMCE creates. So to fix this you should be able to prevent the focus trap behaviour by adding either `disableEnforceFocus` or `disableEnforceFocus={true}`, as noted in the Material UI docs.